# How do create a CSS for Adsense banner move under My content

Tags: html, css

How do create a CSS so that My content is on the left side of the screen and I place the vertical Adsense on the right side, however, the page opens on the smartphone, the Adsense banner move under My content?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Google Responsive CSS

Comment: You have to write media queries.. Learn more about https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn first about [Responsive Web Design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design).

According to this, there are many ways to make a page responsive.
`Flexbox, Grid, MediaQueries & ...`

1. I'm showing you an example using [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
2. You can also read about [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) here.
3. And about [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) here.

Result: As you can see, if the total width of the two boxes would be over `520px`, then it will break into a new line.

```js
const check = () => {
  let firstBoxInput = document.querySelector('.first-child-width').value;
  let secondBoxInput = document.querySelector('.second-child-width').value;

  const firstBox = document.querySelector('.first-child');
  const secondBox = document.querySelector('.second-child');

  firstBox.style.width = `${firstBoxInput}px`;
  secondBox.style.width = `${secondBoxInput}px`;
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', check);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 520px;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.container .first-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px
}

.container .second-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="first-child-width" placeholder="First Box Width in px">
<input type="number" class="second-child-width" placeholder="Second Box Width in px">
<button type="button">Click</button>

<section class="container">
  <article class="first-child">First Child</article>
  <article class="second-child">Second Child</article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Media queries can be used to check many things, such as:

- width and height of the viewport
- width and height of the device
- orientation (is the tablet/phone in landscape or portrait mode?)
- resolution

Using media queries are a popular technique for delivering a tailored style sheet to desktops, laptops, tablets, and mobile phones

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.text{
  text-align: justify;
   padding: 0 10px;
}

.adsense{
  width:100px;
  background-color:#666;
  color:#ffffff;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.container{
  flex-direction: column;
}
.adsense{
  margin-top:20px;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#666;
  color:#ffffff;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class='text'>
<h3>My Content</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div class='adsense'>
adsense
</div>

</div>
```